# Вложенные классы Java

Tags: java

В книге говорится, что вложенный класс имеет доступ к членам внешнего класса. Но в чем проблема здесь и как внешний класс связан с вложенным?

```
class Outer
{
    int outer_x=101;
    void test()
    {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.display();
    }
    class Inner
    {
        void display()
        {
            System.out.println("vivod: outer_x = "+outer_x);
        }
}
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.outer_x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Наследование внутренних классов в java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664622/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вложенный и внутренний - разные понятия. Inner class - это внутренний, который объявлен в любом классе. Nested class - это вложенный, который объявлен в любом классе с модификатором static. У вас Outer - внешний класс, а Test и Inner - внутренние.

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.outer_x;
    }
}
```

Не сработает, т.к. Test является внутренним классом в Outer. У внутренних классов не может быть статических методов. Нужно либо сделать Test не внутренним, либо статическим.

```
Inner inner = new Inner();
```

Не сработает, ибо для создания экземпляра внутреннего класса нужен экземпляр внешнего, вот так:

```
Inner inner = new Outer().new Inner();
```

И, наконец:

```
inner.outer_x;
```

Не сработает, ибо outer_x доступен только внутри Inner. Можно только так:

```
class Outer {

    int outer_x = 101;

    void test() {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.display();
    }

    class Inner {

        void display() {
            System.out.println( "vivod: outer_x = " + outer_x );
        }

        int getOuter(){
            return outer_x;
        }
    }

    static class Test {

        public static void main( String[] args ) {
            Inner inner = new Outer().new Inner();
            inner.getOuter();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вылазит такое :
>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Inner cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Мой код работает. Проверьте фигурные скобки у себя. Сдается мне, у вас Test не внутри Outer.